# How to convert YYYYMX (tm) format characters to dates without string manipulation?

Tags: r, date

I have a monthly data file where dates are stored in `%tm` format of Stata like `2000m1`. How I can convert it to dates?

I could do something like manipulate the strings into `2000-01-01` but I would like to avoid this if possible.

`as.Date('2000m1')` (unsurprisingly) returns `NA`.

Comment: You could look at `parsedatetime` from the `lubridate` package.

Comment: thanks -- actually, it is `parse_date_time()`

Comment: Yes you are right. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) yearmon** Using the zoo package, this converts it to a `"yearmon"` class object which may make more sense than converting it to a `"Date"` given that you have no day of the month.  Such objects are internally represented as a year + 0 for Jan, year + 1/12 for Feb, etc. so they sort properly.

```
library(zoo)

as.yearmon('2000m1', '%Ym%m')
## [1] "Jan 2000"
```

If you really want `"Date"` class then the following give the start and end of month respectively:

```
as.Date(as.yearmon('2000m1', '%Ym%m'))
## [1] "2000-01-01"

as.Date(as.yearmon('2000m1', '%Ym%m'), frac = 1)
[1] "2000-01-31"
```

**2) paste** This does not use any packages and while it does use `paste` it's a fairly minimal use of string manipulation:

```
as.Date(paste("2000m1", 1), "%Ym%m %d")
## [1] "2000-01-01"
```

**Note:** Be sure not to use any solution that returns a POSIXct object rather than a `"yearmon"` or `"Date"` object since then you have introduced the possibility of future potential errors based on time zones into your code which can be completely avoided by using an appropriate class.  See the R Help Desk article in [R News 4/1](https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf).

Comment: `ggplot` works finer with `Date` objects that is why I prefer to get `Date` rather than `yearmon` at the end.

Comment: `zoo` has `scale_x_yearmon()` to interact with `ggplot2`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very easily with the amazing `lubridate` package:

```
data <- c("2001m1","2010m3","2015m12","2009m8")

library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(data,orders="%Y%m"):

[1] "2001-01-01 UTC" "2010-03-01 UTC" "2015-12-01 UTC" "2009-08-01 UTC"
```